# How to verify if a rule exists in a prolog file clause database

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a college assignment where I must verify if a certain clause (as a fact or as a rule) exists in the current clause database.

The idea is to use a rule whose head  is verify(+name, +arguments). This rule should be true if in the database exists another rule whose head is name(arguments)

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `call/1` is not a good idea because `call/1` actually calls the goal, but you just want to find out if the fact/rule *exists*, and you don't want to wait after a long calculation that the call might trigger, and you don't want to have something printed on the screen if the called rule in turn calls e.g. `writeln/1`. In addition, you would want `verify/2` to succeed even if the call failed (but the fact/rule is otherwise there).

As a solution, SWI-Prolog offers `callable/1`

```
callable(+Term)

True if Term is bound to an atom or a compound term,
so it can be handed without type-error to call/1, functor/3 and =../2.
```

Here are two version of `verify/2`, one using `call/1` and the other using `callable/1`.

```
verify1(Name, Arguments) :-
    Term =.. [Name | Arguments],
    call(Term).

verify2(Name, Arguments) :-
    Term =.. [Name | Arguments],
    callable(Term).

father(abraham, isaac) :-
    writeln('hello').

father(abraham, adam) :-
    fail.
```

Comment: verify2 works also for father(abraham, daniel). which doesn't exist. So, I suppose, callable detects if the predicate 'father' exists and doesn't care about arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the concept of unification? What you have to do is: just call a predicate that looks like the one you're trying to find.

So, say in your database is:

```
father(abraham,isaac).
```

Now you want to call something like:

```
verify(father,[abraham,isaac]).
```

Your predicate body will then have to contain a mechanism of calling `father(abraham,isaac).` which should then return `true.` Calling `father(abraham,adam)` should fail.

You will need two predicates for this: `=../2` and `call/2`. If you are using SWI-Prolog, call `help(=..).` and `help(call)` from the interpreter's command line to access the documentation.

I hope I didn't spoil the assignment for you. You still have to find out what to do with partially instantiated predicates (so, say something like `verify(father,[abraham,X]).` on your own, but it shouldn't be hard from here.

Good luck.